# how to display return array value of fetchAll function in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I have created model using following [Zend Framework Quick start tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html).

Now in controller I have call `fetchAll()` function and I am getting value in form of array from model class. This array is look like as ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Admin_Model_Users Object
        (
            [_id:protected] => 1
            [_access_id:protected] => 1
            [_firstname:protected] => test
            [_lastname:protected] => test
            [_username:protected] => admin
            [_password:protected] => 1@3$523456
            [_salt:protected] => 
            [_email:protected] => 
            [_active:protected] => 0
            [_last_access:protected] => 0
            [_created:protected] => 0
        )

)
```

Now I have use `foreach` loop for getting values of array but this time it gives error like:

> Message: Invalid Users Property

I have run `foreach` loop as follow:

```
<?php 
    foreach($this->profile as $myprofile){
                 echo $myprofile->id; 
        } ?>
```

I have tried to solve it and also on Google search. But I am not getting any solution for this. Please tell me, how I can access value of array?

Comment: The error doesn't seem related to the pasted code...

Comment: Can you post your code from model(only function) and a little from controller... because you are doing wrong all stuff...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are trying to access "_id" by using "id".

Have you tried `echo $myprofile->_id;` instead?

If that still isn't working, the tutorial page you linked to points to creating methods in the Admin_Model_Users class for retrieving values.

Particularly, because the variables are protected and should be accessed via a method such as `$myprofile->getId()` (which would need defining inside the Model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using functions like getId(), I can access the values but these all functions are defined in model file and in view file like user.phtml, I don't want to call function like getId(), getFirstname()....etc I simply want to show the all array values.... If you have any idea to solve it please suggest me.. Thanks again for your help..

Comment: @user1414979 If you are able to include a new function in the Model, I would suggest you define a `getAll` function which returns the entire array.